# AngularJS controller attributes

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm newbie on AngularJS, and my first application based on Ionic have main controller with many attributes:

```
.controller('mainPageController', function($scope, $http, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading) {
 ...
}
```

Now i want include more params (ex: $ionicModal ) ecc.
Is some more elagant way to define all Ionic modules used in controller scope ? (when my application expand, will be very large used different modules)

Alb

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I think there is no more elegant way to achieve this in AngularJS 1.